# youtube data api v3のコメント許可の設定方法

Tags: youtube-data-api

こんにちは。

youtube data api のversion 3を使用して動画の更新を行っています。
動画のコメントの許可をする設定がv2ではあったのですが、v3だと見つかりません。
以下ページを参考にしました。
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos?hl=ja#resource

どなたか設定方法をご存知の方はいらっしゃいますか?

Answer (score 1):

現状ではAPI経由でコメントの許可・不許可の設定を行うことは出来ません。次のIssue Trackerで対応していますが、２０１６年2月の段階でもまだ対応はされていません。

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6194

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！返信非常に遅れ申し訳ありません。。